# SQL Server GetUTCDate invalid as default

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, datetime

Using Microsoft SQL Server I want a column to have the current UTC date and time by default. When a row is inserted and a value is not specified for that column it should default to the UTC date on the server.

I create the table with:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Status]
(
    [ProcessNam] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [LastCheckIn] [datetime2] NOT NULL DEFAULT GETUTCDATE(),
    [Failures] [tinyint] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),

    CONSTRAINT [PK_AST_PING] 
      PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProcessNam] ASC)
          WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

But when I use:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Status VALUES ('TEST', '', '')
```

The column ends up containing `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000`

If I use

```
SELECT GETUTCDATE()
```

The correct timestamp is returned.

Comment: `''` is different from `NULL`

Comment: You're providing a value in the `INSERT` - an empty string - that's why the default doesn't get used. You should **explicitly list** those columns you want to insert values into - and if you don't want to insert anything into `LastCheckIn`, then don't include it in the list of columns you're inserting values into - in that case, the default will be used instead

Answer (score 3):

You are inserting '' (an empty string) as the LastCheckIn value so the default is not being used. Try this instead;

```
INSERT INTO DBO.STATUS (ProcessNam) VALUES ('TEST')
```

Because of the way DateTimes are parsed, '' is equivalent to 0 (zero) and because of the way DateTimes are stored, 0 is equal to 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000.

Comment: It is appalling that an empty string seems to be parsed 1900-01-01.

Comment: @usr It kind of isn't - it's parsed as 0. Which translates to 1900-01-01 as datetime (number of days since 1900-01-01).

Comment: you could also use `INSERT INTO DBO.STATUS VALUES ('TEST',default,default)`

Comment: @Aツ I recommend against that - what have you saved? Typing the column names? Why? [You know that it will break as soon as someone adds a new column or changes the order, right](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list.aspx)?

Comment: @Aaron_Bertrand the topic of the question is not the missing column names but the insert of some default values. i would be better to list them all, of course, but again, its not the topic.